# Does Spring AMQP has any advantages over the RabbitMQ Java client?

Tags: spring, rabbitmq, amqp, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I am using RabbitMQ cluster for job queues. I wonder to know if there any features which will simplify interaction with RabbitMQ cluster when we use Spring AMQP? Or it is better to use official Java client?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring AMQP uses the same client under the covers.

Project page [here](http://projects.spring.io/spring-amqp/).

> The Spring AMQP project applies core Spring concepts to the development of AMQP-based messaging solutions.

It's generally a higher level of abstraction (`RabbitTemplate`, POJO listeners with `@RabbitListener` and message listener containers, etc) - if you are already familiar with Spring, you should see many concepts that you are used to.

It doesn't preclude you from using the RabbitMQ client directly.